# Liferay First Start wizard not openeing

Tags: liferay, liferay-ide

I had an old Liferay 6.2 environment that is no longer working well, so I decided to download and run a fresh new environment, so I downloaded the Liferay studio, unzipped it and started the executable, I was expecting to see the First Start wizard that installs the sdk and the server automatically, but this didn't happen and the LR studio finally opened bare with no server installed, even I have no idea if I wished to add the server, where its instance might be, As per what I understand, it's wrapped in one or more of the zip files contained inside.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Liferay Developer Studio 3.0 does not come with a "First Start Wizard" any more, however, Developer Studio 2.2 (the last one that explicitly targeted 6.2) does.

If the First Start Wizard already ran, it won't automatically start again (it's quite particular about that "first" attribute). However, if you look at the top right corner of the eclipse workbench, there's an input field, named "Quick Access". Enter "First" in that field, it will autocomplete to "First Start Wizard" (in DevStudio up to 2.2) and you can run the wizard again this way.

As Liferay 6.2 EE is no longer included in DevStudio 3.0, the wizard to set it up is no longer needed. And the Workspace setup for Liferay 7 / DXP is totally different than the Plugins SDK for Liferay up to 6.2

Answer (score 0):

I don't understand your problem to be honest. Could you please delete ALL your liferay's folders and do this:

1. Install JDK and setting required environment variables (JAVA_HOME, path)
2. Download MySQL server and start server (mysqld --console and mysql -u root -p, ext.)
3. Connecting to MySQL server and create Database for Liferay (write down if you don't know how to do that)
4. Download Liferay 6.2 Tomcat Bundles
5. Download Liferay 6.2 Plugins SDK
6. Download Eclipse LUNA
7. Create Work space folder; extract the downloaded files in work space directory.
8. Configure Liferay Tomcat sever information in Plugins SDK properties file.
9. Start Eclipse and choose liferay prospective
10. Configure Plugins SDK in Eclipse
11. Configure Liferay Tomcat Server in Eclipse
12. Start Server

Could you please do this steps and then write down which point you have trouble with?

Thank you!

Comment: thank u German, actually I am using the Liferay Studio (the commercial version), so it should do steps 4-11 automatically through a wizard called "First Start" ...  the problem is that this wizard doesn't open for some reason that I don't know

Comment: Why don't you want to turn down that Liferay Studio? :D

Comment: because this is the default in our environment, but may be I  will give it a try :)\

Comment: If you have no special demands - I really advise you to do as I said. If you will have any problems - you can ask another question with "liferay" tag and I'll help you. :)

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes due to some missing config or some corrupted file this might occur.
So firstly Liferay plugins SDK may or may not be a part of developer studio but generally server is available as a standalone component.
In case you fo not have LR server,please download it from Liferay site or it's github repo.
In order to configure LR server/Plugins SDK go to Windows->Preferences->Liferay to configure the same.